# How to solve system of particular equations in C (probably using cycles)

Tags: c, algorithm, math, linear-algebra, equation

I´ve run into problem while working on my school project in C.
I am working with two equtions:
**x=a+u*i*** ;
**y=b+vj**

Known is the value of **a, b, u, v**. I need to multiply **u, v** *with natural numbers **(i, j)*** until equality **x=y** occurs.

(Note: i and j may not have a same value/ could be a different numbers while x=y).

And here comes the problem, I dont know how to solve the equations while **i and j differs**, i suppose that possible solution is by cycles, or diofantic equations (I dont know how to apply them to the equations above.)
I am beginner and stuck. Can someone help me with solution in C code, please? Thank you.

**EDIT**
If i just want to solve the equations by the cycles,
I think I know what should I do, but I just dont know how to write it in C..

1) every step of cycle, I count x, y

2) if x is lower then y, i is increased by 1, if not, j is increased by 1

3) its repeating until x=y

4) sometimes the solution is not there at all, so I have to put there a condition so it doesnt run forever.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about elementary algebra and not programming.

Comment: Post your current C solution so far

Comment: This is just a part of computation for my project in C, which I´m not able to solve. I dont want to burden you with the whole problem.

But it might me handy to explain the complex problem (my project). I gonna post here wider explanation asap.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your equations, you get:

```
a + u i = b + v j
```

With the solution

```
i = (b + v j - a) / u
```

Now you need to find a natural number `j`, such that `i` becomes natural. Obviously, `b + v j - a` has to be a positive multiple of `u`. So:

```
b + v j - a = k * u, k \in N
j = (k * u + a - b) / v
```

Now `k * u + a - b` must be a multiple of `v`. This is not always possible. The easiest way to check is to iterate the first few possible `k`s and see where it gets you. If you get a natural number, you can plug the solution of `j` into the above equation and you are guaranteed to get a natural `i`.

This assumes that x, y, a, b, u, and v are real numbers. If they are also integers, you might get a bit farther than that.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, this is very helpful, i will try to incorporate it as a statement to my code :)

Comment: When I compile **k** is undeclared and first used in this function. I am not able to determine where did you take it, or what the k is.

Comment: As I said. It is any natural number. And the easiest way is to iterate `k` from `1` to some upper bound.